# Querying Windows file indexing service using C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

Is it possible to query file indexing service using C#?
Does file indexing service expose a database?
If so what is the scheme of this database?

Comment: you can do this through WMI...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is now called ['Windows Search'](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/default.mspx). Current version is 4.0. A special SDK exists and documentation is readily available in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362(VS.85).aspx)

So the answer is positive: yes, it it possible. Here's the [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266517(v=VS.85).aspx) with more info.