# Use windows search file API

Tags: c#, file, search, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Querying Windows file indexing service using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131420/querying-windows-file-indexing-service-using-c)

How I can use windows search file engine programmatically?
I'm using Windows 7.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft does have a Windows Search [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7388). Take a look at that and see if it has what you need.

Comment: The link which you have provided is currently not available. Please provide a valid link