# Enumerating files of specific type in Windows

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, winapi

Is there a native (Windows API) method to list all files of a specific type (e.g. video files), preferably using the built-in index (the one Windows Search uses)?

Just to clarify, I know that I can use basic FS API to recursively list all files and filter by extension. I want a much faster method which use the Windows Search index.

The programming language does not matter. If you know a possible solution give me an example in any language.

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266517%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Windows Search SDK, see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547413/use-windows-search-file-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned use the Windows Search SDK.

Download the example DSearch from this page: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/windowssearch
and pass in type:video as the userQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I found this tutorial to be the most useful, as it explains how to get the DLL you need for the Windows Search API.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21142/How-to-Use-Windows-Vista-Search-API-from-a-WPF-App

Basically, you need the Windows SDK installed. Then you can run a command line like:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>tlbimp "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\SearchAPI.tlb"
```

To generate the DLL you need. Include that DLL in your project. Then, in c#, add:

```
using SearchAPILib;
```

To your code.

From there, I created a simple object for my search results:

```
public class Result
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ext { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public Result()
    {
        this.Name = string.Empty;
        this.Ext = string.Empty;
        this.Path = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And used this code to conduct the query.

```
public ActionResult Index(string q = "default")
{
    var Results = new List<Result>();
    var cManager = new CSearchManager();
    ISearchQueryHelper cHelper = cManager.GetCatalog("SYSTEMINDEX").GetQueryHelper();
    cHelper.QuerySelectColumns = "\"System.ItemNameDisplay\",\"System.FileExtension\",\"System.ItemFolderPathDisplay\"";
    cHelper.QueryMaxResults = 50;

    using (var cConnnection = new OleDbConnection(cHelper.ConnectionString))
    {
        cConnnection.Open();
        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(cHelper.GenerateSQLFromUserQuery(q), cConnnection))
        {
            if (cConnnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Results.Clear();
                    while (!reader.IsClosed && reader.Read())
                    {
                        Results.Add(new Result() { Name = reader[0].ToString(), Ext = reader[1].ToString(), Path = reader[2].ToString() });
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        cConnnection.Close();
    }

    ViewBag.Results = Results;
    return View();
}
```

And output it using a standard Razor view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            @{foreach(var item in ViewBag.Results){
                <li>Name: <b>@item.Name</b><br />
                    Ext: <b>@item.Ext</b><br />
                    Path: <b>@item.Path</b>
                </li>
            }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A sample query might be: beer AND kind:pics

More info on the query langauge: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How long would it take for the Windows Search to index a new file (e.g. just uploaded from a camera)?