# Get a list of all indexed files in Windows with Delphi

Tags: windows, file, delphi, indexing

I would like to list all the files that windows has indexed using its [Windows Indexing Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexing_Service).

Specified file extensions are acceptable.

For instance: I am working an a software which presents user media such as photos and videos. I am currently using the following custom procedure to find the files myself:

```
function FindAllFiles_Safe(aDirectory, aFilter: string; aIncludeSubDirs: boolean): string;
  {$IFDEF DCC}
  var TD: TDirectory;
      SO: TSearchOption;
      DF: TStringDynArray;
      i: integer;
      sl: TStringList;

      MaskArray: TStringDynArray;
      Predicate: TDirectory.TFilterPredicate;
      {$ENDIF}
begin
  {$IFDEF FPC}
  result:=FindAllFiles(aDirectory,aFilter,aIncludeSubDirs).text;
  {$ENDIF}

  {$IFDEF DCC}
  MaskArray := SplitString(aFilter, ';');


  if aIncludeSubDirs=true then SO:=TSearchOption.soAllDirectories;

  Predicate :=
    function(const Path: string; const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean
      var Mask: string;
    begin
      for Mask in MaskArray do
        if MatchesMask(SearchRec.Name, Mask) then
          exit(True);
      exit(False);
    end;

   //DF:=TD.GetFiles(aDirectory, Predicate, SO);
   DF:=TD.GetFiles(aDirectory, SO, Predicate);

   if length(DF)=0 then exit;


   sl:=TStringList.Create;
   for i := 0 to length(DF)-1 do sl.Add(DF[i]);

  result:=sl.Text;
  sl.Free;

  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Is there a way to access files that Windows has already indexed?
I'd like to take advantage of Windows Indexing Service to quickly retrieve files, rather then wasting resources if Windows already has done it before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumerating files of specific type in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272920/enumerating-files-of-specific-type-in-windows)

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways to [query the index of the Windows Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff684395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is use ADO and the Query Syntax (AQS) and SQL.

Try this sample code (off course you can improve the SQL sentence to filter and speed up the results)

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  ADOInt,
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;


procedure  QuerySystemIndex;
var
  Connection : _Connection;
  RecordSet: _RecordSet;
  v: Variant;
begin;
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_Connection, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IID__Connection, Connection));
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_RecordSet, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IID__RecordSet, RecordSet));
  Connection.CursorLocation := adUseClient;
  Connection.Open('Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=''Application=Windows'';', '', '', adConnectUnspecified);
  Recordset.Open('SELECT Top 5 System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SYSTEMINDEX', Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText);
  Recordset.MoveFirst;
  v:='System.ItemPathDisplay';
  while not Recordset.EOF do
   begin
      Writeln(Recordset.Fields.Item[v].Value);
      Recordset.MoveNext();
   end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      QuerySystemIndex;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

You can found alternatives ways to access the Search Index on the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[There is an API for Windows Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362(VS.85).aspx) (previously known as Windows Desktop Search).

However, whilst the Windows Search API is undoubtedly enormously powerful, I think for simply locating files based on file extension (or even other constituent elements in the file name) the Windows Search API is likely to prove prohibitively complex and provide negligible benefit, unless you are dealing with a truly extraordinary number of files.