# Order by "Relevance Values"

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on Windows Forms application. I want to apply a filter on ListView. The requirement was to implement search feature in windows when searching files with a given name in a folder.

It turns out that Windows is using [**Relevance Values**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231292(v=vs.85).aspx) to order found files.

I was thinking, maybe there is a build in solution in .Net for that?
If not, is there any C# code for this algorithm that I can use to manually  order filtered objects:

```
var searchFor = "search";
var newList = oldList.Select(x =>x.Contains(searchFor))
                     .OrderBy(x => RelevanceValues(x,searchFor))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272920/enumerating-files-of-specific-type-in-windows

Comment: You need a free text search library. Try NuGetting "Lucene.Net". Here's a bit of sample code: http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/09/02/lucenenet-your-first-application/

Comment: Have you solved you problem?

Comment: This link https://www.codeproject.com/articles/21142/how-to-use-windows-vista-search-api-from-a-wpf-app provided by @HansPassant seems to be the best help for me

Comment: Are you looking for sorting a seach result on a `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` by relevance or the question is specifically looking for to the Windows function to search by relevance between files?

Comment: @RezaAghaei sorting a search result on a `List<T>` by relevance using the Windows Search relevance algorithm

Comment: Windows Search relevance algorithm is an implementation for files. It's not related to `List<T>`. You can implement a relevance calculator between `T,K` and then use it in a method like `List<T>.GetByRelevance<T,K>(...)` which  returns you a `List<KeValuePair<T,int>>` which contains calculated relevance scores between `T` and your input. Then you can simply sort based on `Value` of result and the select `Key` from the sorted result.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example to achieve this. This example contain Order By Relevance Values with File list.

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;    

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // textBox1 for search string
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        // listView1 for show result
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }   

        class MyListViewItem : ListViewItem
        {
            public int Index { get; set; }
        }  

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<MyListViewItem> myList = new List<MyListViewItem>();

            // open folder browser to get folder path    
            FolderBrowserDialog result = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (result.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // get all file list
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(result.SelectedPath);
                foreach (string item in files)
                {
                    // find the relevance value based on search string
                    int count = Regex.Matches(Regex.Escape(item.ToLower()), textBox1.Text.ToLower()).Count;
                    myList.Add(new MyListViewItem() { Text = item, Index = count });
                }
            }

            List<ListViewItem> list = new List<ListViewItem>();
            // add file name in final list with order by relevance value
            foreach (var item in myList.OrderByDescending(m => m.Index).ToList())
            {
                list.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = item.Text });
            }

            listView1.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search and order by relevance values using LINQ with Regex. Please try below code:

```
var searchFor = "search";    
var newList = oldList.Select(l => new
        {
            SearchResult = l,
            RelevanceValue = (Regex.Matches(Regex.Escape(l.Text.ToLower()), searchFor.ToLower()).Count)
        })
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.RelevanceValue)
            .Select(r => r.SearchResult);
```