# Fastest Way of Searching a file within Directories and SubDirectories

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, full-text-search

I need the fastest way to search for files within directories and subdirectories. The number of files is more than 1.4 Million. File sizes range between 5 and 50 KB. Each folder contains 5 to 10000 files.

At the moment I am using:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    if (file.Contains(searchkeyword))
    {
        string AnchorText = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use a database? And why are you using `file.Contains(searchkeyword)`. Normally i would search in the file-name instead of the whole path.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter i can't use database not allowed.

Comment: Simply `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Contains`

Comment: @Tim Schmelter thanks.. any help about fastest way to search these files

Comment: Is the date information also specified in the filename? I _may_ have removed a little too much detail from the original post.

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you've given? Also if you can't use a database, perhaps you can use a simple file? Fill it with all file names, perhaps also include a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can update the file when changes occur?

Comment: @Steven Liekens file name doesnot have date information.

Answer (score 1):

**Best Solution**

I would [add an index to that directory](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Folder-to-the-Windows-7-File-Index) and use [Windows Search to find files in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131420/querying-windows-file-indexing-service-using-c-sharp). The advantages here are not only that it isn't code that you need to maintain but also that the Windows Indexing Service is able to index the contents of files (.doc, .pdf, .txt, etc.).

**Home-Grown Solution**

A home-grown cache inside of a database (*Sql, Redis, Mongo, Lucene, whatever you prefer).

1. Subscribe a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to the directory when your application starts.
2. Then perform an enumeration over the directory *once* (as per your original code sample) to ensure that no files were added/removed/changed while your application was not running.
3. Store any data from these two in an appropriately indexed table in a database.

When you need to search for a file simply query the database.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.. how do i use Windows Search in c# to find files in it.

Comment: I provided links - the rest is up to you.