# Windows Search with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, file, search

How to use the standard Windows file search within C# code? Can somebody provide me a simple code sample? I would like to implement a textbox in my application to perform file searching via Windows Search.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4131458/43846) for links to the Windows Search API and SDK

Comment: `GOOGLE is your best friend, try using it`

Answer (score 1):

You can search through those files linearly in O(n)...

```
public void GetFiles(string directoryName, string fileName) {
    return = Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*" + fileName + "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
 }
```

Comment: The point is that I need to do that via Windows Search API because I would like to search files by content too.