# C# Open a process without know location path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

I have to open a process.exe from a button_click event by known only the `filename` and the `.exe` extension.
Is It possible? In two words i need to make a `game.exe` library ,and if the `filename.exe` will be found the process `filename.exe`,
need to be started. 
I want to avoid to ask the costumer the full path of the program location, and i dont want to use `OpenFileDialog()`for browse. Im three days stuck here. So

```
filename.exe=textbox1.text
SystemDiagnostic.Process(..).Start(filename.exe)
```

this will open only the file if the file and the debug program are in the same directory.

Do i need a recursive search, and if the file is found open the process?How do i search for the `filename.exe` in all the `@"C:\`?

Thank everyone Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Is that file deployed by you or other vendor? You cannot even assume it is in the C: volume.

Comment: Other vendor. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If that file is deployed by you, like it is up to you to make an installer for it, you can add the containing directory of that file to the PATH environment variable, then you can simply launch it by

```
Process.Start(“filename.exe”)
```

Without having to specify the full path to that file.

If it is out of your control, but there is some trace about the location of that file, for example, if it is from a known vendor and the file has a default location or there is something like “InstallLocation” in registry for that file, you can query registry to get the full path then launch it.

Your last resort will be scanning the whole disk for that file. But this is too bad, unreliable and slow...and things can go wrong easily. I strongly warn you against this approach.

If you have to choose the last approach, you might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4131420/815938) useful. Remember to check other attributes like version number, publisher, etc., in case you end up calling a wrong file happens to have that name.